# Sailsjs/Passport add fields to User

Tags: node.js, sails.js, passport.js

Sails noob here.  I have sailsjs (v0.12.3) running with passport and everything is currently working.  The User model is located in /node_modules/sails-auth/api/models/User.js and has username, email, and passports fields.  I want to add additional fields (like bday ->string, favorite_car-> string) to the users table, but can't find a good way to do this.  Editing the existing User.js file to add the new attributes would probably work, but seems like a bad idea.  I've tried creating a User.js file (in myproj/api/models/) but i get an error stating:

Error: on mapping custom foreign keys: role->user. Attribute: `roles` does not exist on: collection: `user`

Any insight into the best way to do this would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

added:
I've tried many different iterations from a empty User.js file  (in myproj/api/models/) to the entire code that come with sails-auth (in myproj/node_modules/sails-auth/dist/api/models/User.js).  They all produce the same error.  Here is code that tried from the node_modules' User.js:

```
'use strict';

var _ = require('lodash');
var crypto = require('crypto');

/** @module User */
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    username: {
      type: 'string',
      unique: true,
      index: true,
      notNull: true
    },
    email: {
      type: 'email',
      unique: true,
      index: true
    },
    passports: {
      collection: 'Passport',
      via: 'user'
    },

    getGravatarUrl: function getGravatarUrl() {
      var md5 = crypto.createHash('md5');
      md5.update(this.email || '');
      return 'https://gravatar.com/avatar/' + md5.digest('hex');
    },

    toJSON: function toJSON() {
      var user = this.toObject();
      delete user.password;
      user.gravatarUrl = this.getGravatarUrl();
      return user;
    }
  },

  beforeCreate: function beforeCreate(user, next) {
    if (_.isEmpty(user.username)) {
      user.username = user.email;
    }
    next();
  },

  /**
   * Register a new User with a passport
   */
  register: function register(user) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      sails.services.passport.protocols.local.createUser(user, function (error, created) {
        if (error) return reject(error);

        resolve(created);
      });
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: Please share your /myproj/api/models/User.js code.

Comment: Are you using sails-auth generator?

Comment: I have an [example](https://github.com/makah/sails-social-auth-example) using Passport and a step-by-step README with separate commits, maybe it can help you.

Comment: I found the solution.  I figured there must be a way.  https://github.com/langateam/sails-auth/issues/119